# Foreach loop explanation

Tags: php, foreach

Can someone explain this code structure please?

```
  // Remove all fields and field instances.
  foreach (field_info_instances('node', 'windfarm') as $field_name => $instance) {
    field_delete_field($field_name);
    field_delete_instance($instance);
  }
```

Specifically `as $field_name => $instance`. The way I understand it is that field_info_instances() returns an array and `$field_name` is the item used in the loop. But what is the `=> $instance` part?

I've only seen this sort of foreach so far:

```
foreach ($array as $item) { 
 statement 
}
```

Comment: `field_info_instances('node', 'windfarm')` returns an array and you're then iterating through that array with `$field_name` as the index and `$instance` as the value for each array element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at it like so:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {}
```

So in an array that is structured like so:

`$arr = ['some', 'values' , 'to', 'populate', 'the', 'array'];`

The `$key` would be the array index, `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`
and the `$value` would be `some, values, to, populate, the, array`